# Sorting input file into set character lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading an input file which contains a large amount of data stored as bytes in separate lines. I am trying to sort this data into a new file where each line contains 23 bits. For example, here is a short snippet of the input file to process:

```
00000101
01010000
10000100
00010011
00101001
00011100
01011011
01101000
01001000
11000011
00100011
```

Here would be the output in the new file:

```
00000101010100001000010
00001001100101001000111
00010110110110100001001
00011000011001000110101
00100000011111100110000
00101001111000101111000
0011000100111001010001
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps:

Read actual file contents. Let's say name of file is `data.txt`, replace new line characters and then write 23 charactors and a new line with each iteration into a new file

```
data = ""
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.replace('\n', '')
chunk_size = 23
total_chunks = len(data)/chunk_size + 1
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, total_chunks):
        start = i * chunk_size
        end = (i + 1) * chunk_size
        f.write("%s\n" % data[start:end])
```